# How to stop auto styling on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reveal.js

I have some reveal slideshow that I need to convert to a single page html. I've used jQuery to strip the code of all the reveal.js added classes, javascript, and stylesheets. For some reason, when I resize the page, a style is added to the div that hides half the content.

My code before resizing:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="slides-body">
        <section id="slide-Title">
            <div id="div-Title">
                <h2>
                    My Title
                </h2>
                <button id="button-Single-Page" style="padding-bottom: 5px" class="smallButton" onclick="singlepagehtmlformat()">Click here for the single page html version.</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code after resizing:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="slides-body" style="width: 960px; height: 770px; left: 50%; top: 50%; bottom: auto; right: auto; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.920625);">
        <section id="slide-Title">
            <div id="div-Title">
                <h2>
                    My Title
                </h2>
                <button id="button-Single-Page" style="padding-bottom: 5px" class="smallButton" onclick="singlepagehtmlformat()">Click here for the single page html version.</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Should be some javascript onresize event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the default behavior, there must be a window resize event as pointed by @Bas Van Stein delegated in the code causing that.

To fix, it you can just remove the attr "style" from the target div.

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $("#slides-body").removeAttr("style");
});
});
</script>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/mzg2zk48/2/

Comment: This works, but this would mess up the reveal.js code if the person doesn't click on the button to strip the reveal.js. I'm looking into a jquery on refresh  function for a solution to this.

Comment: You don't need to click a button to get this triggered. This is a window.resize event which would execute everytime the window is resized.

Comment: I have a click button to remove the reveal.js in the case that the user doesn't want to view it in that form. I've figured out how to do this. I dynamically added the script to replace the reveal.js initializing script. Thank you for all your help!